# Regla para quitar directorio de la URL

Tags: .htaccess, pretty-urls

Buenas, estoy configurando mi `.htaccess` para poner en producción mi web y el caso es que no lo termino de entender o no me llevo muy bien con este archivo y me da problemas.

Tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios:

```
index.php
login.php
.htaccess
includes/
    └ panel.php
    └ etc..
```

El `.htaccess` lo tengo configurado ahora mismo así:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Tanto `index.php` como `login.php` funcionan correctamente, ya que me oculta la extensión `.php` como quiero.

El problema viene cuando me logeo y me manda a `panel.php`, me muestra la dirección así: **www.miweb.com/includes/panel**, y no quiero que me muestre el directorio **'/includes/'**.

¿Cómo podría ser la regla que debería configurar o dónde puedo tener el problema en la configuración actual del archivo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es dividir las reglas de redirección en diferentes pasos:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  # Primer paso: ignoramos archivos y directorios existentes
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule .* - [L]
  # Segundo paso: sustituimos coincidencias sin extensión .php en general
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
  # Tercer paso: sustituimos coincidencias en el subdirectorio /includes
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/includes/$1.php -f [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ includes/$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

En cada paso se comprueba la existencia de la sustitución antes de hacerla, para asegurarnos que existe el script PHP de destino.

El primer paso comprueba si existe un archivo o directorio con el nombre solicitado y en ese caso no se hace nada (el `-` del `RewriteRule`).

El segundo paso (que sólo se ejecutará si el primero no se cumple) comprueba si existe la URL que estamos solicitando agregando `.php`.

El tercer y último paso (que sólo se ejecutará si los dos anteriores no se cumplen) comprueba la existencia de la URL en el subdirectorio `includes` agregando la extensión `.php`.

Tendrás que repetir el último paso tantas veces como subdirectorios quieras ocultar, pero ten en cuenta que sólo la primera coincidencia funcionará.

Es decir: si tienes un archivo `hola.php` y otro `includes/hola.php` sólo el primero será atendido y el segundo será enmascarado. La única forma de acceder a él será a través de `includes/hola` (coincidencia en el segundo paso) o `includes/hola.php` (coincidencia en el primer paso).

Comment: Muchas gracias tío, ya entiendo el porque también me daba los errores a la hora de intentar pasarle varias reglas y he podido deducir como ocultar un GET del directorio includes con: 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ includes/$1.php?p=$2 [L]

Answer (score 1):

No le has pedido que te lleve a panel sin mostrar includes. Tendría que ser algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^panel$ /includes/panel.php [L]
```

Esto haría que "www.miweb.com/panel" muestre "www.miweb.com/includes/panel.php".